# Execute Process in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, process, jobs, child-process

I have code in c# working fine which runs a job in a particular server box during my UI automation.I need equivalent code in node js.

```
ProcessStartInfo startinfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startinfo.FileName = string.Format("schtasks.exe");

            string command = string.Format(" /run /s {0} /tn \"{1}\"", "serverbox", "Jobname");
            startinfo.Arguments = command;
            startinfo.CreateNoWindow = true;//Not much important
            startinfo.UseShellExecute = false;//Not much important
            startinfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;//Not much important
            Common.Log.Info("Executing Command - " + command);
            Process proc = new Process();
            proc = Process.Start(startinfo);
```

I have below code in node.js which throws " Incorrect value of args option" error.

```
function executeProcess() {
  var command = new String(" /run /s {0} /tn \"{1}\"", "serverbox", "jobname");
  exec(command, function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log("Running job");
    callback(err, stdout, stderr, data)
});
```

};

Comment: https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String constructor takes only single argument.
Your error is here:

```
var command = new String(" /run /s {0} /tn \"{1}\"", "serverbox", "jobname");
```

To avoid error use javascript feature called `string templates`:

```
const command = ` /run /s "${serverbox}" /tn "${jobname}"`
```

Comment: var command = new String(` /run /s ${"serverbox1"} /tn ${"job1"}`);
    exec(command, function (err, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log("Running job");
        callback(err, stdout, stderr, data)
    }); Still i get "Incorrect value of args option" error.In this where does schtasks.exe come? How should i include that in this code. Please reply with full code since i'm new to node js.

Comment: Why do you want `new String`? Just use ``.

Comment: Just start with something simple like `const a = 'qweqwe'; exec(\`echo ${a}\`, callback)`. Then increase complexity of your command to run process that you need. And you can use `console.log(str)` or `console.dir(obj)` to monitor your values. All arguments goes into the `command`, since there is no `Process.Start(startinfo)` in nodejs.